# NSFileProtectionComplete and Core Data security in Xamarin

Tags: ios, encryption, xamarin.ios, xamarin

There's a lot information and examples how to encrypt or protect files using CoreData and Keychain in iOS applications. But I have trouble to achieve this using .NET and Xamarin. There is way how to use Keychain to store small amount of data. But what about encryption and data/files protection? What I have is app which downloads huge amount of data from webservice and make local cache using sqlite. Now I want to keep the sql file protected AND data in it encrypted. I want it using Xamarin and SQLCipher is not an option.

I'd appreciate your tips and guidances in which direction I should research/think about it.

Comment: Could you clarify your question ? e.g. are you using CoreData or simply sqlite ? (seems the later). Also what information did you find useful (in ObjC) that seems missing for Xamarin ? (e.g. links). In general asking for tips/guidance are not the best fit for stackoverflow (see FAQ).

Comment: The answer depends on which feature of iOS you want to use, they are all available, in different place.s